# What does this Java error message entail? And how can i fix it?

Tags: java, soap, axis

I get this message when trying to communicate with software that communicates with SOAP?

- Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.

I am using a third party API to communicate with an Ardome MAM system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 'normal' error, actually a mere warning. If you really want to use attachments (you problably don't), try adding activation.jar to the classpath of your application server.